# How to obtain gif info (disposal method, frame width/height, frame count) knowing only image Uri without downloading it in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animated-gif

i'm trying to make my gif images animated. i've found some very suitable piece of code here: http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/wpf-display-an-animated-gif-image/

but i faced with next problems: on windows 2003 server, windows xp it is not possible to obtain gif metadata (WIC is available for vista, win7...). and i need to get frame width and height, disposal method and some other data. gif images are obtained through Uri. how can i get necessary data knowing only Uri and without saving gifs on disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the image in to an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7e7b2kd.aspx) object from a stream, and you can create a stream using the URL. This would allow you to create an Image object without saving to disk, and from the object you can get info such as width and height etc. Would this help?

E.g.

```
Image image;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://<insert URL here >");

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(stream);
    }

}

// Use image here...
```